# WPF Animation - How to start an animation from a specific time

Tags: wpf

I have a Storyboard with key-frames animations.
How can I start it from a specific time and not from the beginning of it?

Thanks

**Update**
Never mind, found the answer - set the BeginTime to the negative of time I want it to start on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, found the answer - set the BeginTime to the negative of time I want it to start on